# Django: understanding how to serve static files during development -- NOOB edition

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, static

I am struggling with getting my static files to work. Before one starts posting links to the docs, I have been to and read to the best of my having-completed-the-django-tutorial-level understanding the following links:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

-
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

I will state that I think the second of which is super confusing.

In short, none of my attempts to remedy my issues using the docs have succeeded. So I would appreciate someone walking me through what is going on.

First, I have an app, `my_app`. In `my_app` I have an model which has an image field that looks like this:

```
def my_app_dir_path(instance, filename):
    return 'my_app/static/my_app/images/other_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.other.id, filename)


MyModel(models.Model):
    other = models.ForeginKey("other", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=my_app_dir_path)
```

in short, files that I upload go to the namespaced local static directory:

```
 /my_app/static/my_app/images/other_<id>/<image_file>
```

as it says I should do in (4) under configuring static files for the link howto static files.

Great.

I have a dummy view that I am using to try and see if I can get my image to load:

```
#/my_app/views.py
def dummy(request):
    img = MyModel.objects.first()
    return render(request, 'my_app/dummy.html', {'img':img})
```

which bascially is just this

```
#dummy.html
<img src="{{ img.image.url }}" />
```

looking at the website inspector, we see that the url that is returned is:

```
my_app/static/my_app/images/other_<id>/<image_file>
```

and if - in the inspector - I change that url to

```
static/my_app/images/other_<id>/<image_file>
```

the image appears!

so how do I get - for development - the correct url?

while we are at it:

- what is this convention? ('/var/www/static/')
- am I supposed to add `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to my `urlpattern` in `my_app` or in the root? or both?
- what is the difference between media and static. Are image files (which unless you are using dynamic svgs) not considered static?
- why do I have to compile everything in a global root static / media folder (doesnt that defeat the point of being modular?)

In short, can someone teach me how to serve static images for development?
I am really confused.

Comment: You've confused MEDIA files (uploaded by user when application is running, not checked into version control) with static files (deployed along with application, usually checked into version control). You haven't shown any of your settings (e.g. `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`), which makes it harder to help. Your title says deployment, but your question says development, so it's not clear where you're having trouble. It looks like [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, sorry I meant development in the title (now corrected). The media stuff is however it was when you start a new project. Havent touched it. I dont know what it is or what it does or why it is different from static. I have seen that section, and tried that solution but it does work

Comment: It's not going to work if you haven't set `MEDIA_URL` (e.g. `MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'`) or `MEDIA_ROOT` (e.g. `MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/where/you/want/to/store/uploaded/files/'`).

Comment: @Alasdair what is the difference between media url and media root, and why do I have to set them, when my images are static and upload by admin

Comment: As I said before, Django considers files uploaded by the user (whether or not they user the admin) to be media files, not static files. The docs explain what [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root) and [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-url) are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's terminology isn't perfect. Both "static" and "media" files are static (and in production both should be served by the web server without involving Django). In addition, "media" files can be any kind of file, not just media. A better terminology might have been "app files" and "data files".

"**Static files**" are those that are permanent; they are part of your application. These are typically JavaScript, CSS, and images such as logos and icons.

"**Media files**" are application data. They are, in a way, part of your database, but Django prefers to store them outside the database. Typically these are the files that correspond to `ImageField` and `FileField`.

In **development**, Django automatically serves static files. The only configuration you need is `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. If you have file `my_app/static/my_app/js/myjsfile.js`, Django will serve that at http://localhost:8000/static/my_app/js/myjsfile.js (the `/static/` in the URL is actually specified by `STATIC_URL`). In templates, you typically use something like `<script src="{% static 'my_app/js/myjsfile.js' %}">`, and Django will convert this to `<script src="/static/my_app/js/myjsfile.js">`, but it will work properly even if you decide to change `STATIC_URL`. You typically don't need to do any configuration except set `STATIC_URL` and set `DEBUG = True`.

For media files, you need to specify both `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`. The first one is the directory where "media" files will actually be stored, and `MEDIA_URL` is, well, the media URL, like `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`. This means that http://localhost:8000/media/xxx leads to a media file. You also need `DEBUG = True` here.

In **production**, things are more complicated. I have made [a graphic](https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/) which explains it.

Comment: This helps clarify things a lot. How come new apps automatically have `STATIC_URL` set and not `MEDIA_URL`? Anyway, so lets say I have my ImageField upload to `/media/<app>/<sub-dir(s)>/<image-file>`, what do I set `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` too, and how do I, in a template, get the url?

Comment: Ok, so I got images to appear! but I dont understand why. I am developing on  my local system. So I set `MEDIA_ROOT="<path-to-project-dir>/media/"` and `MEDIA_URL="/media/"` then added `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to the `urlpatterns` inside my app. Why does this have to be under the app?